# Reading .netcore dll from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, .net-core, python.net

I am trying to read a .netcore dll from pythonnet. Dll is loading successfully but while accessing the modules it is  throwing error No module named "module_name"

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("C:\Coredll\Core.Test.dll")
from Core.Test import *
```

Below error is recieved

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "test.py", line 3, in 
>       from Core.Test import *;
>   ImportError: No module named Core.Test

***Note: Otherthan core dll i.e. normal .net framework dll is working fine.***

> Python Version: 2.7
>   Pythonnet latest: 2.3.0

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have started using IRONPYTHON which resolved my issue for .netcore dll
Thanks!!!